# 415 unsupported media type : Got this error in remote server but it was fine in localhost

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

This is my Ajax POST call:

```
$.ajax({
        url : $("#login-form").attr("action"),
        type : "POST",
        headers: { 
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
        },
        dataType : 'json',
        data : JSON.stringify(json),
        success : function(data) {
...
```

And this is Spring MVC request mapping method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    public @ResponseBody String login(@RequestBody User user,
            HttpServletRequest req) {
...
```

Before I posted this post I've read several posts about this problem, they said that I need to declare headers in my Ajax request:

```
headers: { 
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
        },
```

But it doesn't work. More interesting, no error happened when I deployed my application to localhost. But after I deployed it to remote server, I got `415 unsupported media type` when I tried to access my website using my browser. 
Any idea about this? Thanks!

Comment: Try to remove `produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8"`, or at least make it `produces = "application/json"`. Just for an experiment.

Comment: @Alexey I added `charset=utf-8` because I need to return Chinese character

Comment: `produces` restricts media types supported by the controller. It does not change the encoding of your response. See the [Spring Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-produces) for more info on `produces`.

Comment: @Alexey Thank you very much, I have a misunderstanding about `produces` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. My code is all right and it is the JBoss Wildfly's fault. I changed JBoss version from `wildfly-8.1.0.Final` to `wildfly-8.1.0.CR1` then it works!!